# Como atualizar uma lista no tkinter

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde!

criei uma função que atualiza a  lista "mylistcolum" de acordo com os campos de uma tabela buscada no sqlserver.
O evento que ativa essa função é o click em uma lista de tabelas que é exibido no inicio do programa. 
o problema que estou tendo é que  a lista de campos ao invés de ser substituida quando clico em uma nova tabela, está acrescentando os novos campos.
Ao invés de ficar:

> **tabela a:** a.nome, a.end, a.numero 
>   **tabela b:** b.casa, b.carro, b.escolaridade

está ficando:

> **tabela a:** a.nome, a.end, a.numero **tabela b:** a.nome, a.end, a.numero, b.casa, b.carro, b.escolaridade

```
def getTabela(event):

lista = []

#aux = 0
#while aux < mylistcolum.size():
#    if mylistcolum.size() > 0:
#        del mylistcolum[aux]

if mylist.size() > 0:
    tabela = mylist.get(ACTIVE)
    #label.configure(text=tabela)
    cur.execute("select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns where table_name ='" + tabela+"'")
    dadosColum = cur.fetchall()
    for dados in dadosColum:
        if len(dados) > 0:
            lista.append(dados[0])
    for line in lista:
        mylistcolum.insert(END, str(line))
```